# Is it possible to disable escaping globally with mustache java?

Tags: java, mustache

I am using [Mustache Java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) to template regular text files and would like to disable any escaping done to the resource / the interpolated values.

For example, this java code:

```java
var mustache = new DefaultMustacheFactory()
  .compile("templates/test.mustache");
var writer = new StringWriter();
mustache.execute(writer, Map.of("value", "=")).flush();

var content = writer.toString();
System.out.println(content);
```

with this `test.mustache` file:

```
Interpolated data is escaped: {{value}}
```

Will output

```
Interpolated data is escaped: &#61;
```

Which is unwanted since `=` was escaped to `&#61;`.

I am aware that using `{{{` and `}}}` delimiters can escape the interpolation but I wish to have this feature disabled rather than worked around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would just switch to [JMustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache) or [JStachio](https://github.com/jstachio/jstachio) both of which are easier to use and better documented (I'm the author of JStachio).

If your models are type based and not just `Map<String,Object>` then JStachio is good choice (it is vastly faster and safer then mustache.java).

```java
//package-info.java
@JStacheConfig(contentType=PlainText.class)
com.mypackage;
```

Now all templates in that package will do no escaping. If your application is modular you can put the same annotation on a `module-info.java`.

If your models are `Map<String,Object>` and or you do not want to go the more type-safe route I recommend `JMustache`

Doc example here: https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache#not-escaping-html-by-default

```java
Mustache.compiler().escapeHTML(false).compile("{{foo}}").execute(new Object() {
    String foo = "<bar>";
});
```